# Install Mac Dashboard Widget directly from website

Tags: macos, mac-dashboard-widget

We have a dashboard widget for the Mac that we want to provide to our customers.  It seems that the typical delivery method is to have the user download the widget as a zip file then double-click the widget inside of the zip.  Is there a way to directly download the widget without having to take the zip step?  In other words, is it possible to have a button that they click which results in a popup saying something like: "Do you want to install this dashboard widget?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is not possible. Widgets consist of multiple files, so they must be downloaded as some sort of archive (whether it's a `.zip` or something else) and extracted by the user.

Comment: This makes me sad... and annoyed. :(